# How to do AddonPreferences using extensions_framework?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I have seen scripts taking user preference values using classes built over AddonPreferences. Is it possible to do the same using extensions_framework by Doug Hammond. Why I am asking this is I need to get a path to an executable from the user, like a path to a renderer. The script which I made does all its class registration / unregister happens through EF. So is it possible to get the path from pref?

Comment: I think I should provide some starting point for you to experiment with this link contains the code but it is not woking... https://github.com/afilash/BlenderExperiments/tree/master/BlenderExperiments/src/customeRender

Answer (score 1):

**No** (as of 2.68), the Python `extensions_framework` directory has no references to `AddonPreferences`.

You could contact Doug Hammond about this or check on adding support yourself.